# How to partially include Node.js module using rollup with commonjs plugin

Tags: javascript, node.js, commonjs, rollup, bitcore

I'm trying to include [bitcore-lib](https://github.com/bitpay/bitcore-lib/blob/master/index.js) partially into my webpage using tree-shaking that rollup provides out of the box and `rollup-plugin-commonjs` to load Node.js module.

To better illustrate the problem I make a demo project that [available on the github](https://github.com/artall64/sample-node-rollup/tree/master)

You can have a look at `bundle.js`. If I define a module in the following way:

```
const useful = "3";
const useless = "4";

export {usefull, useless}
```

Tree shaking works correctly - the final bundle includes only useful dependency.

But if I define a module in the way it defined in bitcore-lib (`node-lib.js`) in demo project:

```
module.exports = {
    useful: "1",
    useless: "2"
};
```

In that case, the final bundle includes the whole module.

I've expected that `useless: 2` dependency shouldn't be included because of tree-shaking. My index.js is here:

```
import {usefull as usefull1} from "./my-node-lib"
import {usefull as usefull2} from "./my-es-lib"

console.log(`hi! ${usefull1} ${usefull2}`);
```

My `rollup.config.js` is [available here](https://github.com/artall64/sample-node-rollup/blob/master/rollup.config.js)

Is it a problem of module definition or rollup config?

Answer (score 1):

Tree shaking works only for ES6 modules. At least it's true for Webpack and I suppose for rollup as well. Your first definition is ES6, second is commonjs.

Therefore if a library is not compiled/transpiled to ES6 modules tree shaking will not work. 
Another feature which will not work is module concatenation.

Depending on the library you can try to recompile it.

Comment: Seems there are tree shaking should work, but it depends on the CommonJS module itself - see https://github.com/rollup/rollup-plugin-commonjs/issues/362